# How to animate item in Tab Layout when select a tab?

Tags: android, animation, android-tablayout, tabwidget

I want to put an animation when i am taping the tab i want image rotation animation on tab icon. Below is the Example but it is in iOS.

[image]

Comment: SO people won't write code for you. but Somebody gave +1 for your link. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach might work: Create an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` as illustrated here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html and set it as your tab's icon.

Assign a listener to your TabLayout, in `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener#onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)` you have access to the tab's icon using `tab.getIcon()`. Run the animation associated with your `AnimatedVectorDrawable` like so:

```
final Drawable icon = tab.getIcon();
((Animatable) icon).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got a idea from your answer.

Comment: Well what was the idea? @GauravSinghal

Comment: Create AnimatedVectorDrawable and onTabSelected get the icon of particular tab and call ((Animatable) icon).start();  to start particular animation, refer developer link given above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is completely based on animation,I suggest you to follow [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton) demo,this is exactly what you looking for.

```
<com.like.LikeButton
app:icon_type="star"
app:circle_start_color="@color/colorPrimary"
app:like_drawable="@drawable/thumb_on"
app:unlike_drawable="@drawable/thumb_off"
app:dots_primary_color="@color/colorAccent"
app:dots_secondary_color="@color/colorPrimary"
app:circle_end_color="@color/colorAccent"
app:icon_size="25dp"
app:liked="true"
app:anim_scale_factor="2"
app:is_enabled="false"
/>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]